# Does GWT serialization support writeObject() and readObject()?

Tags: java, gwt, serialization

I can't find it anywhere. I can [find](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Server?hl=fr#Does_the_GWT_RPC_system_support_the_use_of_java.io.Serializable) that "The semantics of GWT's serialization are much less sophisticated than standard Java serialization", but nothing about the support for `writeObject()` and `readObject()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT-RPC has its own serialization format. It doesn't support `writeObject()` and `readObject()` from `java.io.Serializer`, but it has its own mechanism, called [`CustomFieldSerializer`](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideCustomSerialization).

Comment: You answer is correct, but doesn't help me in fact. It requires the CustomFieldSerializer files to be in the client and server package respectively, but mine are elsewhere. I'm trying to serialize a subclass instance to a superclass instance and I had good code for outside GWT.
Don't seem to get it right here.
But thanks.